# Solving duplicate rows in (Stata)

Tags: merge, duplicates, stata

I have dataset that is composed of two merged datasets. First, official unemployment figures from country statistical offices, while the other is unemployment figures from the ILO's modelled estimates.

For some countries like Jordan, it is named JOR but JOR_total in another dataset, although it is measuring the same demographic group. This results in having two rows per gender for the same year. However, I essentially want to keep one row per country and per gender.

Below is how the dataset looks like:

```
year      gender     country         unemployment_official         unemployment_ilo
2019      Female      JOR                  19                            
2019      Male        JOR                  8                              
2019      Female      JOR_total                                          17.3                            
2019      Male        JOR_total                                          7.4
```

I would like to change the dataset to look something as below:

```
year      gender     country         unemployment_official         unemployment_ilo
2019      Female      JOR                  19                            17.3                            
2019      Male        JOR                  8                             7.4            
2019      Female      EGY                  17                            22                            
2019      Male        EGY                  5                             9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this before merging the two datasets, with the following:

```
// Removing countries with duplicate entries
drop if country=="JOR"
replace country="JOR" if country=="JOR_total"
```

And it looks as:

```
year      gender     country         unemployment_official         unemployment_ilo
2019      Female      JOR                  19                            17.3                            
2019      Male        JOR                  8                             7.4            
2019      Female      EGY                  17                            22                            
2019      Male        EGY                  5                             9.4
```